# Query to get people born this week

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get the records where the birthday falls within this week but my `query` returns the people who were born between `Tuesday and Monday`. I want the people born between `Monday and Sunday`. How can I change my query?

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'WW') = TO_CHAR(BIRTHDAY_DATE, 'WW')
```

Comment: *query, edit and change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you who respones my question. I found the solution. Here I create a string of the day,month in current week:

```
DateTime sdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1 * (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek + 1);
        string findDay = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            findDay += (findDay.Length > 0 ? "," : "") + "'" + sdate.AddDays(i).Day.ToString("00") + "." + sdate.AddDays(i).Month.ToString("00") + "'";
```

And the sql:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(BIRTHDAY_DATE, 'DD.MM') IN (" + findDay + ")
```

The 'WW' works like elrado said.

Answer (score 2):

Probably Monday is not first day of your week.

Under system you can get NLS_TERRITORY value with:

**show parameters NLS_TERRITORY**

Under **any session** you can set it like that

Set it for current session.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=slovenia
SELECT to_char(to_date('13.01.2013','DD.MM.YYYY'),'d') from dual;--SUNDAY
```

**Result is 7.**

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY=america
select to_char(to_date('13.01.2013','DD.MM.YYYY'),'d') from dual--SUNDAY
```

**Result is 1.**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```
WHERE BIRTHDAY_DATE between sysdate - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'WW')) + 1 AND sysdate - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'WW')) + 7
```

Comment: Run the below sql and check if the period is falling from a Monday to Sunday. `SELECT (sysdate - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'WW')) + 1) , (sysdate - (TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'WW')) + 7) from dual`